# Copy paste issue with IE11 editor

Tags: javascript, java, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

While i copy the bulletins from word to html editor, the styles are not maintained properly
this is from when i convert word to html

A.      Main
Heading 1

1.       Item
1

2.       Item
2

3.       Item
3

This is from when i copy the bulletins from word to htmleditor and i took the source code

Main
Heading 1

Item
1Item
2Item
3
Please refer the below image links for what it looks

Document image: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/910034 
Editor image: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/910035

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i had conversation with the IE team, they suggest me to use to the ie compatibility mode or u can downgrade your IE version to your previous version where these tags are working fine.